# How to detect active connection from bluetooth device using Android SDK

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I am working on an Android app that uses a bluetooth connection, and I want to read data from the device into the app, but need to know if I am connected to the device before reading data.

Below is the code I have that launches bluetooth settings where I can pair the device. How do I verify that the device that I have paired has an active connection to the app and is ready to send data?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentOpenBluetoothSettings = new Intent();
            intentOpenBluetoothSettings.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intentOpenBluetoothSettings);
        }
    });

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pair** and **Connect** are two different concepts. Your code only pairs a target Bluetooth device and remember it, whose information can be retrieved by calling:

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getBondedDevices();
```

This function actually will return all the information of paired Bluetooth devices even though these devices are not near (connect to) you phone.

To connect a Bluetooth device, you need to write your own connection code and choose a specific UUID to tell your phone which type of connection (serial, audio, etc.) you want to establish.

To learn more about connect to a Bluetooth device, please see the [official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) under **Connecting as a client**.